# Using magit for the most basic add, commit, push

Tags: magit

I normally use only a few git commands each time I want to commit changes to a repository:

```
$ git add --all .
$ git commit -m "update."
$ git push -u origin master
```

Can magit be useful in this regard? `M-x magit-status` seems helpful but I am not fulling understanding the language of "staging/unstaging" "hunks" etc. from [ref1](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Magit) [ref2](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-magit-emacs-mode-git) [ref3](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Staging-and-unstaging.html).

What might be the equivalent commands in `magit`? Thanks in advance -

**Edit** This [page](http://jr0cket.co.uk/2012/12/driving-git-with-emacs-pure-magic-with.html.html) seems to speak better to my level but is `C-u s` the equivalent of `git add --all .`? Though that page says it does not work.

Comment: For simple git use, the vc-mode commands are perfectly suitable. I do use magit for complex commits etc., but for simple cases vc is excellent.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

- <kbd>S</kbd> stages all files
- <kbd>c c</kbd> initiates a commit. Write the message and then press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to actually create the commit.
- <kbd>P u</kbd> pushes to the upstream branch. In the popup that appears after you have pressed <kbd>P</kbd> you can see the upstream. If the upstream is not set yet, then you can still use <kbd>P u</kbd>. You'll be asked for a branch which is then configured as the upstream before pushing.

Comment: It took me some time to figure out what to actually provide after pressing `P u` when the upstream is not yet set. In case your remote repository has the shortcut name `origin` as set in `.git/config` as `[remote "origin"]` and if your branch is called `my-new-feature` then you need to type `origin/my-new-feature` into the minibuffer after `P u`.

Answer (score 2):

This one is also quite easy technique without learning shortcuts of magit by using `hydra`.

```
(defhydra yt-hydra/help (:color blue :hint nil)
  "
_mp_ magit-push #_mc_ magit-commit #_md_ magit diff #_mla_ magit diff #_mla_ magit status
"
  ;;Magit part
  ("mp" magit-push)
  ("mc" magit-commit)
  ("md" magit-diff)
  ("mla" magit-log-all)
  ("ms" magit-status)
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'yt-hydra/help/body)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just write an easy shell function to help PUSHING ALL.

```
function lazy-git {
    git add -A
    git commit -a -m "  $1"
    git push
}

lazy-git "Update somethinng"
```

or in Emacs

```
(defun push-all (comment)
  (interactive (list
            (read-string (format " Push for [%s]: " (current-directory-name)))))
  (save-some-buffers t) ; save all buffer
  (shell-command (format "git add -A; git commit -a -m \" %s\"; git push &"
                     comment)))
```